# Why doesn't this function save information more than once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this function that takes in dynamic data and saves it to some variables. Very simple and it works...but only the first time I save data. After that, it just holds the information and does not refresh.

**Controller**:

```
$scope.savedata=function(cal,time,title){
    $rootScope.rescal=cal;
    $rootScope.restime=time;
    $rootScope.restitle=title;

    $scope.dater = new Date();
    $scope.monthly = $scope.dater.getUTCMonth()+1;
    $scope.day = $scope.dater.getUTCDate();
    $scope.sdater = $scope.day+"/"+$scope.monthly;

    $rootScope.resdate = $scope.sdater.toString();

}
```

**HTML**:

```
   <p style="border:2px solid black;" ng-click="savedata({{totalcalc}},{{totalTime}},'{{choice.title}}')">Saved Date</p>
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks :)

Comment: Its not clear from your example, anyways, if I understand you right: did you try to add `$root` before  `totalcalc ` ? like: `$root.totalcalc` etc .... Also you dont need set `{{}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the {{ }} from function in DOM

```
 <p style="border:2px solid black;" ng-click="savedata(totalcalc,totalTime,choice.title)">Saved Date</p>
```

Comment: You saved my life...thanks so much! It sucks being a noob at this stuff

Comment: you are welcome , but please make this answer accepted! :)